# Is it possible to use Multiple Self Joins in One Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Hi is it possible to use multiple self join in one model just like the code below. the brief overview of my association

- A **User** can have many admin, manager, team leader, staff, and
  client.
- An **Admin** can have many manager, team leader, client and staff
- A **manager** can have many team leader, staff and client
- A **Team leader** can have many staff and client
- A **Staff** belongs to team leader and can have many client.
- A **Client** has many staff and also belongs to team leader.

**Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :manager, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "admin_id"
  belongs_to :admin, class_name: "User"

  has_many :team_leader, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "manager_id"
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "User"

  has_many :staff, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "team_leader_id"
  belongs_to :team_leader, class_name: "User"

  has_many :client, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "team_leader_id"
  belongs_to :team_leader, class_name: "User"

  has_and_belongs_to_many :client , class_name: "User", foreign_key: "client_id"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :staff , class_name: "User", foreign_key: "staff_id"

end
```

and my **Database Table**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :admin_id
      t.integer :manager_id
      t.integer :team_leader_id
      t.integer :staff_id
      t.integer :client_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The manager up to clients is a roles where roles is also an authorization 
as an admin i can create a user where i will assign him her to here role like manager then i can also assign him a subordinate like team leader and a staff to team leader and a client to handle by team leader. And under team leader he can only see staff and client assign to him hope that will clear things

Comment: What did you try and what problem do you face?